# best way to denote the infobox of a map marker as clickable

Tags: maps

I have a set of markers on a map. when the user click on the marker, an Infobox  opens up.

When the user clicks the Infobox, the app will open a streetview for that  marker. However it is not intuitive that the Infobox is clickable (see image below).

What is a good UX to let user know that this infobox is clickable?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can show clickable text on your info-box, I think that will help user to understand the clickable thing more clearly.

something like this-

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Actually information box is used to display info asserts, so making it click able will not be a good idea. Alternative to it, you can still use information box, but allow use to trigger street view through click interaction. Make sure button size on application are optimal enough. [What is the optimum button size of touch screen applications?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/39023/what-is-the-optimum-button-size-of-touch-screen-applications)

Please see, image below as reference.

[image]