# What is recommended spacing between controls for a fat finger friendly interface?

Tags: gui-design, user-expectation, touch-screen

I have tried searching anything related to fat finger friendly sized controls and spacing between. I could only find that it is a [common rule](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/119395/what-size-of-a-button-can-a-reasonably-fat-finger-comfortably-click) to make controls at least 44 pixels big (from what I understood, that would be both in height and width).

I was unable to find anything related about the space between those controls. Would anyone have any more information regarding what the recommended amount of pixels between controls (e.g. buttons) would be for a fat finger friendly interface?

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, is there any reason for you to target specifically "fat finger people" ?

Comment: I would allow my users to make use of touch driven devices @Brice, excuse me for not noting that down. Other than that it is for the sake of making user experience as simple as possible and as fast as possible for any type of user. (meaning it is not necessarily fat-finger focused only)

Comment: Don't use pixels for reference. Phone displays differ in pixel density.

Comment: What would you recommend as alternative instead? @Tooniis

Comment: @Barrosy [Device-independent pixels (dp)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device-independent_pixel)

Answer (score 1):

The space between buttons will depend on the size of the button. If you have only two buttons at the bottom of the screen (for a phone design), you could split the entire width of the screen into two parts without leaving any space in between. And that will work because the width of the button is relatively large. An acceptable width as such (including margins for small buttons) would be about 72px.

Answer (score 0):

https://material.io/design/layout/spacing-methods.html#spacing
I guess the general practice is to define columns and grids and provide atleast 2column width as spacing. For better ease of interaction we can provide half of min control width so that errors can be prevented.